# How do I set up communication between the "Seeeduino Xiao" and the "Adafruit Bluefruit LE UART Friend - Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)"?

Tags: bluetooth, adafruit

I've seen normal Arduino boards connecting to it no problem (Uno, Nano, etc.). I'm trying to connect it to my Seeeduino Xiao. It has UART compatible pins, so I'm fairly certain wiring isn't an issue. I think I'm having a hard time with the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out. For anyone that has this problem to:

First, use the "blueart_cmdmode" example file. Then, follow these steps:

HOW TO GET THE SEEEDUINO XIAO TO WORK WITH THIS

1. Make sure the "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART ble(Serial1, BLUEFRUIT_UART_MODE_PIN);"
   line of text above the "void error" line is UNCOMMENTED. Everything else in that
   block is to still be commented.
2. Define the pins in "BluefruitConfig.h" as such:
   #define BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_RXD_PIN       6    // Required for software serial!
   #define BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_TXD_PIN       7    // Required for software serial!
   #define BLUEFRUIT_UART_CTS_PIN         0    // Required for software serial!
   #define BLUEFRUIT_UART_RTS_PIN         -1   // Optional, set to -1 if unused
3. Wire the pins as defined above.
4. Make sure the Bluefruit is switched to "CMD" mode.